# -webkit-box-reflect conflict

Tags: css, media-queries

Sorry I can not explain it with words, so I will put to you this video 40 seconds, which demonstrates. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CV_fZCPBr8

Basically, the background changes on the *Gallery Format* and *Quote Format* buttons and they lose their reflection. This happens when you resize the browser and back.

And this is the URL: http://www.feya.us

Thank you

Comment: Can you share some relevant code?

Comment: You can't describe the background changing after re-sizing the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following code from `.category_No6` (appears twice in the default.css file: http://www.feya.us/wp-content/themes/Feya/css/default.css)

```
-webkit-box-reflect: below 5px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0%, transparent), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.4)))
```

And similar under `.category_No13` (twice again).

Once that is done, you will find that box around the buttons will vanish and also the image reflection will also reappear.

There seems to be [issues with -webkit-box-reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-box-reflect) according to Mozilla:

> Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: Thank you Vagish. But then I'll lose reflect in a while I need it.

Comment: It seems the `-webkit-box-reflect` feature won't work that well according to the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-box-reflect) on it.